# How to stretch image bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having problems stretching this image
[image]
I found solution to get in there, but it won't stretch to the full.
How do i stretch it?

Comment: Could we see the code?

Comment: Add it in a `.container-fluid` instead of a `.container` or make it a background image in a `<div>` surrounding your `.container`. Next to that: please add some code inside the question or perhaps make a jsFiddle or Codepen showing the problem.

Comment: Sometimes a simple css snippet like this works: `width: auto; height: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are wrapping an entire page in `.container` which makes your website have fixed with. You need to use `.container-fluid` in order to make it stretch to browser width. Note that you can mix those two:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- your topbar with menu here -->
</div>
<div class="container-fluid my-image">
    <!-- your image here -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <!-- rest of your page here -->
</div>
```

Use `img-responsive` class on your image if you are using html `img` tag, or if you want to go with css background property you can add another class to your `.container-fluid` and then style it like so:

```
.my-image {
    background: url(image.jpg);
    background-size: cover; /* will stretch the image to your div size while maintaining aspect ratio */
}
```

For CSS solution you are gonna need to have height of your div defined in some way, it can be fixed of course which will not look good on small mobile devices or you can maintain an aspect ration of that div by doing `padding-bottom: 60%` where the percentge is calculated according to the aspect ratio (i.e. `100%/60%` is `5/3` aspect ratio).

Answer (score 0):

simple use "container-fluid" class name instead of "container"

here is the sample code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="someimage.png" />
</div>
```

make sure there are no parents to this container with "container" class,

this should be direct child to the body.

Comment: shouldn't there be a `row` there?